# Pushing values from struct type to a queue

Tags: c++, struct, queue

I am trying to check if push to a queue container(still confused about containers)is successful.But I'm unable to print the front and last elements of the queue.Help is much appreciated.The error is when I try to try to do cout the front of the queue ready_q.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;

const int process_cnt=22;


struct process{

  int at;
  float bt;
  float rt;};

 process init_q[process_cnt];

 void read_file(ifstream& inData,process init_q[]);

 int main(){

      ifstream inData;

      read_file(inData,init_q);

      queue<process> ready_q;
  for (int i=0;i<process_cnt;i++){
      ready_q.push(init_q[i]);
      cout << "The first element is " << ready_q.front()
  << " and the last element is " << ready_q.back() << endl;  /*check if push to ready_q was successful*/

      }



  cout<<"Test";

  return 0;
  }

 void read_file(ifstream& inData,process init_q[]){


 inData.open("input.txt");

 while(inData){
      for(int i=0;i<process_cnt;i++){
      inData >>init_q[i].at >> init_q[i].bt;
      cout <<init_q[i].at<<" "<<init_q[i].bt<<endl;/*check if read was successful*/
  }
  cout<<"Read Successful in read_file"<<endl;
  }
 inData.close();

  }
```

Comment: `ready_q.front()` and `ready_q.back()` return a reference to a `struct process`. A structure. `operator<<` on a `std::ostream` only knows how to format elementary data types, like numbers and strings. It has no idea what to do with some strange structure. You are responsible for writing the code to format and print this structure, in whatever way makes sense for you.

Comment: thank you Sam.Any suggestion how to print is appreciated since I'm a beginner.

Comment: If you're a beginner you should be using and reading a C++ book, which should have examples that you can try, that do these kinds of things. There are several ways to do it, one of them would be to overload the `<<` operator. Again, I'm assuming that you are trying to learn C++, in which case you should simply continue to read and study the information in your book, in which case this answer will be sufficient.